# Python with selenium: access iframe whose src is returned by javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe

I'm completely new to selenium and javascript. The webpage that I'm working on uses javascript to do certain authentication and construct the url for a frame.

The code looks something like:

```
<iframe id="main_contents"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseUrl = 'http://xxxxxxxxx.com/';
function init() {
    gadgets.io.makeRequest(baseUrl+"auth/", function(obj) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("main_contents");
        if (obj.data.status == 'OK') {
            iframe.src = baseUrl+"?xx="+obj.data.xx;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }, params);
}
```

I have tried to directly locate the frame with `find_element_by_tag_name` but of course its src is empty. I have no idea how to switch to this frame. Could anyone suggest? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to this `iframe` using their `id` attribute value as well as below :-

```
driver.switch_to_frame("main_contents")
```

Or if this `iframe` takes time to load on the `DOM`, you should try to switch using [`Explicit Waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) with `WebDriverWait` to wait until `iframe` available to switch as well as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("main_contents")))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have tried that, it doesn't work. There was no error but the session is not switch to the frame. Ex, I tested

Comment: `frame = browser.find_element_by_id("main_contents")`
`print (frame.get_attribute("src"))` there is no output

Comment: @Seraph if there is no error, how could you know it didn't switch to iframe?? Did you find some element after switching inside this iframe?? And do you want to switch iframe element or want to get it as src attribute value??

Comment: And make sure src attribute value is present in iframe as well

Comment: Yes, I mean there was no error for the switch operation, but when I tried to locate an element in the frame it raises NoSuchElementException.

Comment: @Seraph Then this is the problem with that element which do you want to locate, make sure you're trying to locate with correct locator and implement some waits to wait until element present and let me know then if you have any problem

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally figured it out that the session will first jump to an invisible frame A and redirect to frame B immediately. A and B have very similar src and I was not aware of the existence of frame A. I thought selenium is in frame B but actually it's stuck on frame A.